# Are there any implemented game controls like a screen (thumb) joystick? - iOS

Tags: open-source, ios, motion-control

I'm looking for some open source game controls.
Especially I'm looking for a thumb screen joystick to move a character on the screen, something like a touch circle.

Are there any open source implementation of what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a button and virtual joystick implementation for cocos2d called "[SneakyInput](https://github.com/sneakyness/SneakyInput)". Here's a [tutorial](http://www.qcmat.com/sneakyinput-joystick-dpad-and-buttons-for-cocos2d/) that might help you use it.